# JavaFX Is it possible to prevent combobox from closing when it lose focus?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

Im trying to make additional element for combobox that will control items inside it. My problem is auto-close when losing focus. Is there any way to prevent combobox from auto-hiding/closing?

OK As commentators requested, I tried to set custom skin to my combobox (It's just String Combobox btw), but when I open it I got error

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.getEditor(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:189)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.lambda$new$0(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:76)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty.notifyListeners(Node.java:7718)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setFocused(Node.java:7771)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.setWindowFocused(Scene.java:3932)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.lambda$new$0(Scene.java:3954)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setFocused(Window.java:452)
    at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.changedFocused(WindowPeerListener.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$3(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:149)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1273)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyFocus(Window.java:1252)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin.focusLost(ComboBoxBaseSkin.java:99)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin.lambda$new$4(ComboBoxBaseSkin.java:87)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty.notifyListeners(Node.java:7718)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setFocused(Node.java:7771)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.setWindowFocused(Scene.java:3932)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.lambda$new$0(Scene.java:3954)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setFocused(Window.java:452)
    at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.changedFocused(WindowPeerListener.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:101)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$3(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:149)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1273)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyFocus(Window.java:1252)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.getEditor(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:189)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.lambda$new$0(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:76)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty.notifyListeners(Node.java:7718)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setFocused(Node.java:7771)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.setWindowFocused(Scene.java:3932)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.lambda$new$0(Scene.java:3954)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setFocused(Window.java:452)
    at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.changedFocused(WindowPeerListener.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:101)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$3(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:149)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1273)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyFocus(Window.java:1252)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So it moves us to:

```
@Override protected TextField getEditor() {
    // Return null if editable is false, even if the ComboBox has an editor set.
    // Use getSkinnable() here because this method is called from the super
    // constructor before comboBox is initialized.
    return getSkinnable().isEditable() ? ((ComboBox)getSkinnable()).getEditor() : null;
}
```

Im using this code:

```
        ComboBox gvl = (ComboBox) getScene().lookup("#customCombobox");
    gvl.setSkin( new ComboBoxListViewSkin<String>(gvl)
    {
        @Override
        protected boolean isHideOnClickEnabled()
        {
            return false;
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: Could you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935457/how-to-avoid-closing-popup-menu-on-mouse-clicking-in-javafx-combobox

Comment: Yeah, Im catching NullPointerException error, that is not related to my function calls https://pastebin.com/f4LMRkZ4

Comment: @user1798736 Please paste this error into your question as formatted text, if it is relevant to the question.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. I would suggest use ListView or create own component with Combobox and with a button to control. It's hard to say because I don't know why you need it.

Comment: @Patres im trying to insert inside combobox something like filter for items

Comment: @Patres ok i thought about solution like yours, but tried to ask, looks like ListView with button is a better solution for that

Comment: why? anyway, getting debugging help requires a [mcve]